# К дню или КО дню?

Tags: орфография, предлоги

Как правильно: "К Дню рождения" или "Ко Дню рождения"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возможны оба варианта; словари
> отмечают, что предлог ко употребляется
> со словом день в значении
> приуроченности к какому-нибудь
> событию: подарок ко Дню учителя,
> предлог к – без значения
> приуроченности.

Comment: (С) Справка на Грамоте.  
А вы не знали?

Answer (score 3):

При нагромождении нескольких  согласных к предлогу обычно добавляется "о": во, со, ко, обо: во дворе, со мной, ко двору, обо всех

Answer (score 3):

Добудьте из собственной вашей памяти некоторое число примеров на
предлог "к", "ко" -- старое "къ", и вы заметите, что там, где за ним следует
скопление согласных, употребляется "ко": "ко
мне", "ко всякой всячине". А где этого "многосогласия" нет -- "к моему
дому", "к разной разности", -- там появляется сократившаяся до одного
согласного форма "к".
Это правило из книги В. Л. Успенского "По закону буквы". Так что смело им пользуйтесь и готовьтесь **ко** **Вс**емирному дню мужчин! (2 ноября)

Comment: Источник неубедителен.
Успенский - популяризатор науки, не более.

Comment: но науки же!

Comment: @Лорана, не читайте до обеда советских газет. Уровень Успенского - пятый класс общеобразовательной школы. Это не упрек, это целевая аудитория.

Answer (score 0):

Нормативно - "к дню". В число случаев, требующих обязательного "ко", не входит. Вообще число таких случаев с обязательным "ко" очень невелико, по сути ограничивается местоимениями ("ко мне") фразеологизмами и поговорками ("дорого яичко ко Христову дню"). (По Аванесову).

Но в поэтической или эпической речи "ко" возможно. Отсюда и "ко дню рождения" в соответствующих контекстах.

Кстати, "день рождения" пишется со строчной.

Comment: Боже, тролли, вы уже начали атаку минусами?  А по сути добавить нечего?  
Что, интересно, в ответе не понравилось? Только то, что оно точнее вашего?

Comment: Один минус мой. Поскольку ответ неверный. Второй минус — из аудитории.

Comment: И мой. Согласна с Мариной.

Comment: Жаль, что в нашей "паре" нет модераторов.
Для behemothus: краткий, внятный, по делу ответ — это не троллинг. Переход на личности, отслеживание ответов отдельных участников, манера вести себя по принципу "в каждой бочке затычка" — это троллинг. Возможно, просто отсутствие воспитания, образования, внутренней культуры — ряд можно продолжить.

Comment: Тогда вы перестанете трорллить форум?

Comment: Так, хватит флуда! Все разборки - в личку. Минус снимаю - ответ вполне имеет место быть.  
Надеюсь, все сделали выводы и учтут на будущее свои ошибки.  
Администрация.

Comment: Будет исполнено! )
Но не в минусе дело...

Comment: Девочки и мальчики! Давайте не засорять форум перепалками и уколами. Нет времени читать все это. Обратите внимание, что я не встреваю в эту "дискуссию". А почему? А потому что я самый старший (если не сказать старый) из вас и ценю свое время, которого и так на все не хватает.Будем же мудрее и станем игнорировать любые прорвавшиеся эмоции, отделять зерна от плевел!

Answer (score 0):

Написание зависит от значения. Предлог *ко* употребляется со словом *день* в значении приуроченности к какому-нибудь событию: *подарок ко дню рождения*. Предлог *к* -- без значения приуроченности: *относиться к дню рождения холодно*.

Comment: Я отношусь к своему дню рождения без всякого восторга.