# Беда с предлогами: К или КО, С или СО?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

1. ***К*** входу или ***ко*** входу?
2. ***С*** множеством или ***со*** множеством?
   (Большая пустующая территория **с** множеством офисов, никого из сотрудников нет, в том числе и сторожа.)
   http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1296050-k-vhodu-ili-ko-vhodu-kak-pravilno.html   https://otvet.mail.ru/question/62066888
3. *Белый лев **с** львицей* или ***со*** львицей?

Comment: Вопрос о *с* и *со*: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416857/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be

Comment: Вопрос о *к* и *ко*: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11701/%d0%9a-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%9e-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e

Answer (score 1):

Можете ознакомиться с ответами на подобные ворпросы:

[Предлог "с" или "со"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416857/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be)

[К дню или КО дню?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11701/%d0%9a-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%9e-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e)

Там есть ссылки и на другие ответы.

Как мне кажется, строгих правил на этот счет нет.

Частотность в Нацкорпусе:

*с/со множеством* — 480:1019 вхождений;
*к/ко входу* — 160:273 вхождения.

Лично я в спорных случаях следую неписанному "закону благозвучности": при нагромождении нескольких согласных к предлогу обычно добавляется *о*.

Comment: Нажал ссылку - вопрос "с цветами". "Закон благозвучности" не действует: "со цветами" - звучит нелепо. Насчет моего случая - заменил все спорные места. Вместо "лев со львицей" - "семейство львов". Тяжелый случай...

Comment: Да, есть устойчивые "единицы", не ясно, чего больше, подчиняющихся правилам или исключений.